# How to split ggplot2 with long x-axis into 2 rows?

Tags: r

I have a figure with a very long x-axis (the final image is 2500x400) and I want the figure to be split into 2 rows so it's not so long. Here is my code:

```r
valXdodge = 0.7
ggplot(data = side_effects, aes(x = Drug, y=Middle, colour = System, group = System)) + geom_point(position = position_dodge2(width = valXdodge),size=2,alpha=0.5) + geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max), lwd=2.5,alpha=0.5, position = position_dodge(width = valXdodge)) + ylab("Incidence") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10)) + theme_minimal()
```

I've tried using `facet_wrap` but I'm not sure if I'm using it right.

Comment: Hi Summer. Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It should be possible to do what you ask, but without having a reproducible sample of your data, we can't run your code or see what your plot looks like. The answer is probably to add a dummy faceting variable conditioned on `Drug` and facet by that. However, without knowing the exact format of your data we can't be any more specific than that. Please consider an [edit] of your question and copy-pasting the output of `dput(side_effects)` into it. It would be easy to help you if you do this, but almost impossible without.

Comment: Summer, on top of below, I recommend that you trouble shoot by restricting your code to the problem. That will help you identifying the issues quicker. For the given fragment, remove the `geom_linerange()`, theme()` etc. Good luck with fixing the plot

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by @Allan Cameron, it is difficult to help without a reproducible example.

But what you want to do can be done with basic {ggplot} and a `facet_wrap()` layer.
The following should get you going:

```
library(tidyverse)

# let's create some playdata
# Note: we create a "long" table for ggplot

playdata <- iris |> 
    as_tibble() |> 
    group_by(Species) |> 
    summarise(across(.cols = Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, .f = mean)) |> 
    pivot_longer(cols =  Sepal.Length:Petal.Width
                 , names_to = "Name"
                 , values_to = "Value")
```

Now we plot it

```
playdata |> ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x = Name, y = Value, fill = Species), position = position_dodge())
```

[image: simple ggplot without wrapping]

Adding a `facet_wrap` layer:

```
playdata |> 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_col(aes(x = Name, y = Value, fill = Species)
            , position = position_dodge()
     ) + 
# we set the number of cols to 2 to make it "wrap" to new row
    facet_wrap(.~ Species, ncol = 2)
```

[image: wrapped plot]

So what you need in your data is a variable/column that allows you to wrap the table (presentation).

Alternatively, you can subset the table in 2 groups (e.g. x < 100, and x >= 100) and plot each subset individual.